# How to pass ${__threadNum} value in selenium javascript?

Tags: jmeter

I used Webdriver sampler and write selenium -Javascript. Now in my script for achieving some result we need total number of users so I want to know how add ${__threadNum} value in my script?
or is there any way when multiple users run and some operations execute for only  one user?

Answer (score 1):

- Either put the `${__threadNum}` function to the "Parameters" section and refer it in the script as `WDS.args[0]` where required

  ```
  var threadNum = WDS.args[0]
  ```
- Or use `WDS.ctx` shorthand for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) class, there you will have access to [getThreadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html#getThreadNum--) function. It will return zero-based number of thread so to get the same value you will need to increment it by 1

  ```
  var threadNum = (WDS.ctx.getThreadNum() + 1)
  ```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered) article for more information if needed